# ExpandableList not displaying list on screen

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview

I'm trying to implement a search `Activity`, which contains a `ExpandableList` displaying Songs, Albums, Artist in separate groups.

The queries are all working fine and the adapter is getting the correct search results. But the list is not displaying on screen.

Here is the code:

SearchActivity:

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

    private EditText etSearchBar;
    private ExpandableListView lvExpSearchResult;
    private SearchExpandListAdapter expand_adapter;
    private Cursor cursor;
    int columnIndex;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

        etSearchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearchBar);
        lvExpSearchResult = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExpSearchResult);

        etSearchBar.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence paramCharSequence,
            int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence paramCharSequence, int paramInt1,
            int paramInt2, int paramInt3) {
        ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups = new ArrayList<ExpandListGroup>();
        ArrayList<String> result = null;

        ExpandListGroup trackSection = new ExpandListGroup();
        result = getQueryResult(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        trackSection.setName("Tracks");
        trackSection.setItems(result);

        ExpandListGroup albumSection = new ExpandListGroup();
        result = getQueryResult(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
        albumSection.setName("Albums");
        albumSection.setItems(result);

        ExpandListGroup artistSection = new ExpandListGroup();
        result = getQueryResult(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        artistSection.setName("Artist");
        artistSection.setItems(result);

        groups.add(trackSection);
        groups.add(albumSection);
        groups.add(artistSection);

        expand_adapter = new SearchExpandListAdapter(this, groups);
        Toast.makeText(this, "onTextChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable paramEditable) {
        lvExpSearchResult.setAdapter(expand_adapter);
        Toast.makeText(this, "afterTextChanged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(this, ((Integer)expand_adapter.getChildrenCount(1)).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private ArrayList<String> getQueryResult(String columnToDisplay) {
        String searchQuery = etSearchBar.getText().toString();
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (searchQuery.length() > 0) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM };

            String queryString = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=" + 0
                    + " AND " + columnToDisplay + " LIKE \"%" + searchQuery
                    + "%\"";

            cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, queryString, null, columnToDisplay
                            + " COLLATE NOCASE");

            for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor
                    .moveToNext()) {
                columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(columnToDisplay);
                result.add(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
            }
        } else {
            result.clear();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class SearchExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups;

    public SearchExpandListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ExpandListGroup> groups) {
        this.context = c;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public void addItem(String item, String group) {
        if (!groups.contains(group)) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                    "Error while adding item in group " + group,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        int index = groups.indexOf(group);
        ArrayList<String> children = groups.get(index).getItems();
        children.add(item);
        groups.get(index).setItems(children);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<String> children = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        String child = children.get(childPosition);
        return child;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        String child = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_child_item, null);
        }
        TextView tvChild = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvChild);
        tvChild.setText(child);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        ArrayList<String> children = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return children.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        ExpandListGroup group = (ExpandListGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.expandlist_group_item, null);
        }
        TextView tvGroup = (TextView) view.findViewWithTag(R.id.tvGroup);
        tvGroup.setText(group.getName());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see your toas messages in afterTextChanged?

Comment: yes...the list is getting populated, seems some adapter problem... using ExpandableListAdapter first time...so not confidant if I implemented correctly